# How to select a file from device and send it to server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, file-upload

I am developing an small application where when user tap on a button then a prompt will open and user can select any file like the browse option and send it to server. In iOS there are any option to do that. If yes, then please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS each app runs in its own sandbox and there's just no single place where user files are stored and from which to select them. You can implement file selection only from files previously put inside your particular app sandbox.

Comment: Thanks. Then there are any option to select a file run time and first I have stored it into my app document folder then retrieve it from document folder.

Comment: There's no built-in 'open file' dialog, you have to implement it manually if you need.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem is sandboxed. You have access to files that are saved via your app. Also you can access things like contacts, photo library, etc. with user permissions. There is no iOS equivalent to Mac OSX Finder.